# Kile for Ubuntu 15.04: Closed live preview and can't get it back

Tags: kile, live-preview

Whilst editing a Latex document in Kile, I closed the external live preview window and now seem unable to get it back.

It is enabled and set to external window mode in Settings>Configure Kile and enabled under Build>Live Preview.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling and nothing seems to work so I'm now at a loss.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the Kile saved ini settings file to make it as if fresh installed:

1. save your work and close Kile if opened.
2. Type/paste this in a terminal window (it renames the Kile settings file so you can compare the old and the new versions later): `mv ~/.config/kilerc ~/.config/kilerc.old`
3. start Kile.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I imagine it should be possible to do this without deleting the ini file. do you think I'm missing something or that it's a bug?

Comment: You're welcome. Can't tell, I don't have Kile installed. You  might wanna try and replicate the issue, compare the ini files and maybe file a bug if the case may be.

Answer (score 0):

At least for Kile 2.9.93 for ubuntu 20.04, it works doing this:
go to Settings => Configure Kile => Kile => Live Preview